# Hiding field and field name from view if table is empty

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a page that displays views for the fields of a project. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish: If the table data is empty (for example, no data for City has been inputted in the form) then I want to hide both the field and the field name/label. As seen here:
[image] 

So the fields Notes, City, and Branch should not show up. How can I accomplish this?

Here is my view page code:

```
<div class="projects view">
<h2><?php echo __('Project'); ?>: <small><?php echo h($project['Project']['title']); ?></small></h2>
<div class="well">
    <dl>
        <dt><?php echo __('Name'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['title']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Url'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['slug']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Notes'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['description']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Branch'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['test']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Type of Work'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['type']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Street Address'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['street_address']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('City'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['city']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('State'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['state']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Supervisor'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['supervisor']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Supervisor Phone'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['supervisor_phone']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('# of Workers Needed'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['workers']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Hotel Name'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['hotel_name']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Hotel Address'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['hotel_address']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Hotel City'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['hotel_city']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Hotel State'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['hotel_state']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Hotel Phone'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['hotel_number']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Total # of Rooms'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['room_number']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Hotel Notes'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['hotel_notes']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('PPE'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['ppe']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Phases'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['phase_count']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('% Completed'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($project['Project']['percent_completed']); ?>%
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Start Date'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo $this->Layout->displayProjectDates($project['Project']['date_start']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('End Date'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo $this->Layout->displayProjectDates($project['Project']['date_end']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Project Duration'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo $this->Time->dateDiffDays($project['Project']['date_start'], $project['Project']['date_end']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Archived'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo $this->Layout->boolYesNo($project['Project']['archived']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Created'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo $this->Layout->displayTimeDefault($project['Project']['created']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Modified'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo $this->Layout->displayTimeDefault($project['Project']['modified']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Now i'm assuming the code will look something like this?:

```
        <?php if (!empty($project['Project']['city'])) { } ?>
```

I'm still learning PHP and not very experienced, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need to see my controllers to get a better idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample, that should work for you:

```
<?php if (!empty($project['Project']['test'])): ?>
                <dt><?php echo __('Branch'); ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php echo h($project['Project']['test']); ?>
                    &nbsp;
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what i need it to do!

Comment: @seth care to explain why you un-accepted my answer and accepted this one? Seems like there's an error in this answer as well ($contact variable does not exist in your code)

Answer (score 1):

I usually check if it's is NULL instead of empty. But the logic is that you check the value which is city. So if it is NULL you simple skip it. And just trim the data to make sure that it really is empty because there might be a space in between and you won't know why it's still printing it.

Hopefully you are using the "foreach" loop right? Because if you aren't, you'll need a lot more logic coding.

Answer (score 1):

Although your `!empty()` approach is a proper solution, you may consider automating this process a bit. Considering that all fields are in an array, you can "loop" through the array and only output a row if the value is not empty.

Be careful when using `empty()` in PHP though, because PHP will consider any 'falsy' value as 'empty' (e.g. `null`, `0`, `''`, `false`) will be considered empty, so a 'zero' will *not* be output.To prevent this, do a 'strict' compare against empty strings. You may also need to check against `null` values *and* check if `value` is a 'scalar' value, and not (for example) an array (which is possible if the Model has associations with other models)

By using an array, you won't have to repeat the check for each field and the view may even be re-usable for various actions in your website

Example;

```
foreach($project['Project'] as $name => $value) {
    if('' === trim($value) {
        // skip empty values
        continue;
    }

    ?>
    <dt><?php echo __($name); ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo h($value); ?></dd>
    <?php
}
```

Note that you'll have to add proper 'translations' for the field names in a .po file (read the chapter on localizations, for example;

app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po

```
msgid "type"
msgstr "Type of work"
```

Comment: Glad I could help, and enjoy CakePHP. As an additional 'excercise', you may wrap this code in a 'Helper', this way you can use it *anywhere* in your application without having to repeat your code. This will keep your Views cleaner and easier to maintain (DRY). This chapter describes how to make your own helpers; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers